# Small Basic checking if letter is working

Tags: logic, smallbasic

I've been coding a small basic hangman. It is not working, as it has a logic issue, where it can't flag whether a letter is in  a word or not (letters that are in the word are being flagged as not in the word)

Here is the code

```
  Start()
  Sub start
  GraphicsWindow.clear()
  textbox = controls.addtextbox(150, 100)
  graphicswindow.fontsize = 24
  GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(0, 400, 500, "Please less than 15 characters.")
  graphicswindow.DrawBoundText(100, 50, 400, "Word to Guess")
  Controls.TextTyped = type
  start = controls.AddButton("Start Game", 150, 200)
  Controls.ButtonClicked = btnclicked
  hang = 0
  win = 0
  endsub

  Sub win
    GraphicsWindow.fontsize = 48
    Controls.AddButton("Restart", 0, 100)
  endsub
  Sub hangm
    If hang = 1 then
      GraphicsWindow.DrawEllipse(975, 100, 50, 50)
    ElseIf hang = 2 then
      GraphicsWindow.Drawline(1000, 150, 1000, 225)
    elseif hang = 3 then
      GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(950, 175, 1050, 175)
    elseif hang = 4 then
      GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(1000, 225, 950, 275)
    elseif hang = 5 then
      GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(1000, 225, 1050, 275)
      GraphicsWindow.fontsize = 48
      revive = Controls.AddButton("Restart", 0, 100)
      endif
    endsub  
    
    Sub letters
      temp = 0
        For i = 1 To u
          If Text.GetSubText(t, i, 1) = letter Then
            x = Text.ConvertToUpperCase(letter)
                GraphicsWindow.FontSize = 36
                GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(200 + 70* i, 160, 70, x)
                temp = 2
                win = win + 1
              Else
                If temp = 0 then
                temp = 1
              EndIf
            EndIf
            EndFor
            If temp = 1 then
                hang = hang + 1
                hangm()
              elseif win = u then
                win()
              endif
  endsub
  sub type
    t = Controls.GetTextBoxText(textbox)
  EndSub
  sub btnclicked
    If Controls.LastClickedButton = revive then
      start()
      elseif controls.lastclickedbutton = start then
        graphicswindow.Clear()
        GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(800, 300, 1200, 300)
        graphicsWindow.DrawLine(900, 300K, 900, 50)
        GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(900, 50, 1000, 50)
        GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(1000, 50, 1000, 100)
        graphicswindow.drawboundtext(0, 0, 200, "Make sure to be on Full Screen")
        u = Text.GetLength(t)
        enter = Controls.AddButton("Submit", 300, 350)
        v = Controls.addtextbox(300, 300)
            For i = 1 To u
              graphicswindow.DrawRectangle(200 + 70 * i, 200, 70, 20)
            endfor
          elseif Controls.LastClickedButton = enter then
                letter = Controls.GetTextBoxText(v)
            If Text.GetLength(letter) = 0 then
              GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(300, 400, 200, "Please write a letter.")
            elseif Text.GetLength(letter) = 1 then
              letters()
            elseif Text.GetLength(letter) >= 2 then
              GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(300, 400, 200, "Please write only 1 letter.")
           EndIf
            EndIf
     EndSub
```

I tried to add specific points where the code would make a check, but those didn't seem to occur

Comment: `graphicsWindow.DrawLine(900, 300K, 900, 50)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your text to subtext and not checking it in the if loop